# Mysql & PHP Error

Tags: php, mysql

Well right now i am trying to generate a report(excel file) so i have two input type in a form and when i click submit the php generates the file but i am getting an error saying no record found ,  why ?The column name in my database for the date is order_time and the data type is datetime so the format is example :- 2014-02-18 05:25:38 this way ? So my main problem is how do i make both work together so i guess like sql statement will work for this but how can i imppletement it and also i know i cant declare same variable like this but i am confused how to , Help would be appreciated alot :)   Below is link for the full code of php i am using just for reference and Below is also a short code of what i am doing

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('ProjectDatabase12345',$con);

$order_time=$_POST["datefrom"];
$order_time=$_POST["dateto"];


$query = "SELECT * FROM ss_orders where order_time='".$order_time."' limit 60";
$header = '';
$data ='';
$export = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\nNo Record(s) Found!\n";                        
}

header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n$data";
```

Comment: That's a text **you** print when `$data == ""`. I wouldn't call that "MySQL & PHP Error"...

Comment: but it gives an error no report found inside the excel file

Comment: "No report found" or "No Record(s) Found!"?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario its almost same sir

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario help would be appreciated sir :)

Comment: I think another problem is you're echoing and printing statements in the same file (I presume) you're downloading your excel sheet from. That isn't usually possible

Comment: You're apparently not aware of the relationship between code and output. I'm not sure how I can help under those circumstances: this is a site for programmers I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2014-02-18 05:25:38 is a very very specific time to query. You're only using one of your variables. You probably mean something like this:

```
$from=$_POST["datefrom"];
$to=$_POST["dateto"];
SELECT * FROM ss_orders where 
order_time >= '".$from."' AND 
order_time <= '".$to."' limit 60
```

Also, switch to mysqli or PDO and sanitize those inputs. If this is a public form you could be subjecting yourself to sql injections. mysql_ functions are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to express your value.  You have a select * statement but how does the code know which value to get and where to put it?  It doesn't.

Also, I would not use mysql_fetch_row when returning more than one row, consider using [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)